# rb4: rb7 on change interrupt

Tags: pic

I am using a pic 6f628a and I want to use "on change" interrupt on pins RB4:RB7
I also want to use two different interrupts on pins RB4 & RB5 so when either of the pins have a valid change the flag will be set >>> my problem is how to differentiate between the two interrupts coming from RB4 and RB5. I Want to check the flag of RB4 or RB5 but i don't know how to write this line of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You would check the state of the PORTB pins you are interested. You can also store their status on a global variable for comparison on the next time around, this would allow you to determine which pins have changed. Here is a sample of what your CN ISR might look like:

```
void __attribute__((interrupt,auto_psv)) _CNInterrupt(void)
{
    unsigned char ChangeVector;

    IFS1bits.CNIF = 0;  //clear interrupt flag

    ChangeVector = (PORTB&0xf0)^LastPortB;  //bit vector of changed pins of interest
    LastPortB = PORTB&0xf0; //store value of PORTB pins of interest for the next ISR

    if (ChangeVector&0x10)  // routine for RB4
    {<do stuff here>}
    if (ChangeVector&0x20)  // routine for RB5
    {<do stuff here>}
    <...repeat for other pins>
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the flag be cleared AFTER the port B read, or does that not make a difference as long as the read iis in the ISR?

Comment: Looks good except that I think (PORTB&0xf0)|LastPortB should be replaced by (PORTB&0xf0)^LastPortB ... i.e. "exclusive OR" rather than "inclusive OR" is needed to find out which bits have changed.

Comment: @ScottSeidman It depends. If you clear it at the start like I did and another interrupt occurs, then the interrupt flag will be set again and the CPU will re-enter the ISR immediately upon exiting and servicing any higher-priority interrupts that also occurred. It may actually make more sense to place the flag clear right after the PORTB state is recorded, so as to minimize the chance of missing a pin change.

Answer (score 0):

That PIC has a single interrupt flag for the interrupt-on-change functionality. It doesn't record which pin was changed.

So, assuming that your interrupt service routine is handled before the pins return to their idle state, you would do the following in the ISR:

(please forgive the pseudo-code; i'm not by my computer at the moment)

1. Is the interrupt-on-change flag set?
2. If so, read the current state of the PORTB register into a variable.
3. Now, assess the variable to see which pin has changed.
4. Clear the Interrupt flag.

Comment: IIRC, it's possible to miss the value if it changes before the interrupt is serviced, so it's best not to use this function if it matters and if the inputs could be short-lived.

Comment: Where else can the read happen if not the ISR?

Comment: @ScottSeidman you can read PORTB anywhere in your code. The purpose of this interrupt is to give you an alternative to polling PORTB (or PORTA) in order to see if anything has changed.

Comment: @KGregory -- the interrupt, so far as I understand, is triggered by a change from the value in the port B latch, which is latched on a read.  If you don't do a read *in the interrupt*, you'll just trigger a new interrupt when you exit the routine.  I know some PICS work that way, but I'm not sure about all.  See http://www.piclist.com/techref/postbot.asp?by=thread&id=%5BPIC%5DPortB+Interrupt+on+change%3F&w=body&tgt=top  -- also, where can the read happen FASTER than in the interrupt?

Comment: It may depend on how you have the I/O pins configured and/or which PIC you have. I am using code similar to what I posted in my PIC24F32KA302 and it works fine for me. I'm not sure if it may work differently in his PIC16.